# iPad Landscape only (left or right)

Tags: iphone, ipad, landscape

I am building an app and I would like it to be landscape only, even if rotated.
After reading around, I have set up  aline of code like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation { return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);}
```

This works, but I would like the interface to rotate but always in landscape mode only, with left or right home button, like many other apps do...

How to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{ 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, just need to support *all* landscape orientations, most easily done using the `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape` macro.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation { 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A useful link to describe how to build a landscape only app in iPhone, but it also works in iPad.
http://www.dejoware.com/blogpages/files/iphone_programming_landscape_view_tutorial.html